# why did the Doctor choose the face of Lobus Caecilius

Tags: doctor-who

in the fires of Pompeii the doctor meets Lobus Caecilius

> CAECILIUS: Who are you?
>
> DOCTOR: I am Spartacus.
>
> DONNA: And so am I. 
>   CAECILIUS: Mister and Mrs Spartacus.
>
> DOCTOR: Oh no, no, no. We're not, we're not married.
>
> DONNA: We're not together.
>
> CAECILIUS: Oh, then brother and sister? Yes, of course. You look very much alike.

then after saving him from the volcano  at Christmas 2013 the time of the doctor he regenerates into Lobus  face then in series 8 episode 1 Deep Breath he starts wondering why he choose this face

> DOCTOR:Er, have you seen this face before?
>
> BARNEY: No.
>
> DOCTOR: Are you sure?
>
> BARNEY: Sir, I have never seen that face.
>
> DOCTOR: It's funny, because I'm sure that I have. You know, I never know where the faces come from. They just pop up. Zap. Faces like this one. Come on, look at it, have a look, come on, look, look, look. 
>   (The Doctor pulls Barney over to look in the mirror on the ground.)
>
> DOCTOR: Look, it's covered in lines. But I didn't do the frowning. Who frowned me this face? Do you ever look in the mirror and think I've seen that face before?
>
> BARNEY: Yes.
>
> DOCTOR: Really? When?
>
> BARNEY: Well, every time I look in the mirror.
>
> DOCTOR: Oh, yes, yes, yes. Fair enough. Good point. My face is fresh on, though.
>
> BARNEY: Er 
>   (Barney moves away from the nutter in the nightshirt.)
>
> DOCTOR: Why this one? Why did I choose this face? It's like I'm trying to tell myself something. Like I'm trying to make a point. But what is so important that I can't just tell myself what I'm thinking?

then in series 9 episode 5 The Girl Who Died he starts to realize why he choose  this face

> DOCTOR:I'm not supposed to. Oh. Oh! 
>   (He looks at his reflection in the water and sees what he saw in the mirror back in Deep Breath.)
>
> CLARA: What? What's wrong?
>
> DOCTOR: My face.
>
> DOCTOR [memory]: Who frowned me this face? Why this one? Why did I choose this face?
>
> CLARA: Doctor, what's wrong with your face?
>
> DOCTOR: I think I know why I chose it.
>
> DOCTOR [memory]: It's like I'm trying to tell myself something.
>
> DOCTOR: I think I know what I'm trying to say.
>
> DONNA [memory]: (to Doctor 10) Just someone. Not the whole town. Just save someone.
>
> DOCTOR 10 [memory]: Come with me. 
>   (A memory of Lobus Caecilus cowering as Vesuvius erupts in Fires of Pompeii. Played by Peter Capaldi, if you'd forgotten.)
>
> DOCTOR: I know where I got this face, and I know what it's for.
>
> CLARA: Okay, what's it for?
>
> DOCTOR: To remind me. To hold me to the mark. I'm the Doctor, and I save 
>   people. 
>   (He shouts at the sky - the Time Lords.)
>
> DOCTOR: And if anyone happens to be listening, and you've got any kind of a problem with that, to hell with you!

which made me think why did the Doctor choose the face of Lobus Caecilius? was it like reminder to save people what was it

Comment: Yes, but did he deliberately choose the face or was the face chosen for him?  There's never been any hint in any previous regenerations that he has any control over the outcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have Peter Capaldi's previous acting roles in the Doctor Who universe ever been addressed?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70873/have-peter-capaldis-previous-acting-roles-in-the-doctor-who-universe-ever-been). Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85786/do-we-already-know-how-the-doctor-gets-his-bodies-or-faces

Answer (score 8):

You have the answer right there in your quotes:

> DOCTOR: I know where I got this face, and I know what it's for.
>   [...]
>   DOCTOR: To remind me. [...] I'm the Doctor, and I save people.

He chose the face of the man he saved from Pompeii, to remind himself that he saves people.

Comment: how is this To remind me. [...] I'm the Doctor, and I save people. show  why did the Doctor choose the face of Lobus Caecilius can you at lest give a better explanation please

Answer (score 1):

The Series 4 episode [The Fires of Pompeii](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fires_of_Pompeii_(TV_story))

> featured a guest appearance of Peter Capaldi, who would later portray the twelfth incarnation of the Doctor, and the fact he shared the appearance of a character in this story was not ignored. This would become an important aspect of that Doctor's identity when he made the connection that his face was taken from someone he previously met.

The Series 9 episode [The Girl Who Died](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Died_(TV_story))

> was notable for revealing the origins of the Twelfth Doctor's face: he had unknowingly taken on the likeness of Lobus Caecilius, a man whose life the Tenth Doctor had saved.

From [Lobus Caecilius's Tardis Wikia page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lobus_Caecilius):

> The Doctor later took on the face of Caecilius when he regenerated into his twelfth incarnation. (TV: The Time of the Doctor) Although unsure why his new face appeared familiar at first (TV: Deep Breath), he came to realise that it was to remind himself that his purpose as the Doctor was to always save people — no matter how impossible or "wrong" it might seem. (TV: The Girl Who Died)

In [The Girl Who Died](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Died_%28TV_story%29):

> the Doctor discovers that using the Mire helmet has drained Ashildr's heart, leaving her dead. The Doctor is left brooding about the loss, with Clara trying to comfort him, saying he couldn't save her. He snaps back, saying he can do anything, but the Laws of Time prevent him from doing so. then he starts Looking at his reflection, the Doctor suddenly remembers back to when he first saw it, wondering once more "who frowned me this face?" It's at that moment that the memory comes back to him; Donna Noble had encouraged him to always try to at least save someone even in a fixed point, and he saved Lobus Caecilius' family from Pompeii's destruction. He tells Clara that he chose this face to remember to always save someone, no matter how impossible or wrong it seemed. The Doctor then yells to the sky:
>
> "I'm the Doctor, and I save people. And if anyone happens to be listening, and you've got any kind of a problem with that, to hell with you!"
>
> The Doctor had previously wondered where he had gotten his face, and had theorised he was trying to tell himself something. (TV: Deep Breath) He finally realises his face matches that of Lobus Caecilius and that the message he was telling himself was to save a person, even if it meant breaking the rules of time. (TV: The Fires of Pompeii)

Comment: Is this just a copy-paste job from the Tardis Wikia?

Comment: is that wrong i thought this is a good anwser

Comment: You should at least credit and link to your source. It is a reasonably good answer, yes (although the question [has already been answered before](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105358/31394)).

Comment: karen gillian who plays amelia pond makes a cameo in the exact same episode so theres techinaclly 2 doctors and 2 companions in the one episode

Comment: Thanks for adding your sources to this answer! :-) I just edited it a bit so it's clear which bit comes from where - you might like to have a look at how I did it so you'll know how to do a cited answer next time.