# In-universe reason for Peter Purves having two distinct parts in "The Chase"

Tags: doctor-who, character-motivation

This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38956/has-there-ever-been-an-actor-who-has-portrayed-the-doctor-but-was-previously-fe) asked about actors who appeared in *Doctor Who* as various characters and then went on to play the Doctor. This question is about the First Doctor story *The Chase*. In this story, Peter Purves played two characters – Morton Dill (in the episode where they land on the Empire State Building) and Steven Taylor (the final episode on Mechanus, where he becomes a companion). Is there are in-universe reason for this? Was Morton Dill supposed to be an ancestor of Steven Taylor? Out of universe, was this cheapness, or perhaps someone didn't turn up?

Edit: Coincidentally I am just reading "Who's There? The Life and Career of William Hartnell" by Jessica Carney. On page 167 she writes "One day Bill [William Hartnell] and Maureen O'Brien [Vicki] hatched a plan. They decided they liked Peter Purves when he  did a one-off character role in an early episode of a Dalek story, 'The Chase'; so they went to the producer and suggested him for the role of Stephen Taylor ....."

Comment: Very interesting to hear about Bill and Maureen's role in this. That completes the story I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that he was cast in that serial as a recurring character (the American hillbilly, Morton Dill) and the producers liked him so much that they cast as a new recurring player, Steven Taylor, who made his appearance later in the same serial, and then carried on into the next series.

Note that he grew a stubbly beard specifically so that audiences wouldn't get the two characters confused, suggesting that there was no in-universe connection.

> **Q: You played two characters in the same story – how did that come about?**
>
> **PP: Because I successfully played Morton Dill, the American Hillbilly, I was asked to join the series permanently.** The new character, Steven, appeared in episode six of The Chase. I grew the beginnings of a beard as a disguise between times.
>
> <sub><sup>[Peter Purves: Taylor Made](https://web.archive.org/web/20101202051737/http://totalscifionline.com/interviews/3204-peter-purves-taylor-made)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 12):

Peter Purves was a young actor at the time, just 26 at the time, and beginning to build his career. He auditioned to play one of the Menoptra in *The Web Planet*, and did not get the role, but according to this [interview](http://www.peterpurves.net/doctorwho.html)

> the director, Richard Martin,... very kindly told me that with the
> work I had been doing previously it wasn't worth me playing one of the
> non-speaking roles. However, he told me that if ever he was casting
> proper acting parts, he would think of me.

A few months later, Richard Martin indeed cast Purves as Mervyn Dill in *The Chase*. Purves recalls:

> I was thrilled to be playing the part, but even more thrilled when I
> was asked to go with the Producer, Verity Lambert, for a drink at
> Studio 3, the pub opposite the Riverside Studios. I was dumbfounded
> when she asked me if I would be interested in joining the cast on a
> regular basis. Naturally I said 'Yes' and Steven Taylor made his debut
> appearance three weeks later.

So, as he remarked in another [interview](https://indiemacuser.co.uk/2017/02/06/interview-peter-purves-doctor-who)

> in effect Morton Dill was my audition for the part of Steven Taylor.

The two characters he played seem to be completely unrelated, so there is no in-universe reason for the casting. It just seems to be that he impressed the producers sufficiently for them to offer him a permanent role.